# scons "Import of non-existent variable" env: how to fix?

Tags: python, import, environment-variables, scons

I'm hoping that all SConscript could share the environment definition from SConstruct, like this:

cat ./SConstruct

```
import os,sys
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
env.SConscript(dirs=['mydir'])
```

Then under ./mydir

cat ./SConscript

```
Import('env')
env = env.Clone()
```

I try to run it:

```
scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: *** Import of non-existent variable ''env''
File "/home/john/mydir/SConscript", line 1, in <module>
```

So why scons failed to "Import env", is my syntax wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: A variable that should get "imported", has to get "exported" first. Where in the documentation (MAN page, UserGuide, ...) did you find a reference to the `Import()` method, but `Export()` wasn't mentioned somewhere close by? Just asking to possibly improve our docs in some places...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dirkbaechle said.
Change your SConstruct to:

```
import os,sys
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
env.SConscript(dirs=['mydir'], exports='env')
```